# Getting string as input from user

Tags: c

look at the code given below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter a string : ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("String : %s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

output will be,

Enter a string : Hello world

String : Hello

my question is why it take only first word as input?

Comment: `scanf()` reads to first whitespace

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods

Method 1:

```
scanf("%[^\n]",str);
```

Method 2:

```
fgets(str, MAX_LIMIT, stdin);
```

Comment: Please edit the answer to exclude `gets()`. That function is obsolete and dangerous. Even the manual page says "Never use this function." See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used](reasoning)

Comment: Method 2 is wrong

Comment: @klutt ohh sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: And I have to say that method 1 seems a bit odd. Looks like you're about to read one character extra after the newline. What's it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

> my question is why it take only first word as input?

Because that's exactly what the documentation says that the `%s` specifier should do:

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/